# Error when using a function: Error in df1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, function, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the gun laws from https://www.statefirearmlaws.org/. However, I keep getting the following error:

Error in df1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

I used selector gadget to copy the nodes for the table.

What can I do to fix it?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

years <- lapply(c(2006:2018), function(x) {
  
  link <- paste0('https://www.statefirearmlaws.org/national-data/', x)
  
  df1 <- link %>%  read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('.js-view-dom-id-cc833ef0290cd127457401b760770f1411daa41fc70df5f12d07744fab0a173c > div > div') %>% 
    html_text(trim = TRUE)
  
  df <- df1[[1]]
  return(df)
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- link %>%  read_html() %>% 
html_nodes('.js-view-dom-id-cc833ef0290cd127457401b760770f1411daa41fc70df5f12d07744fab0a173c > div > div')
```

this part results in `{xml_nodeset (0)}` which later produces empty `list()`.

Are you selecting the correct thing you want to scrape in `html_nodes`? Maybe SelectorGadget can be helpful to choose what you need

Comment: Selector gadget is actually what I used :/ I highlighted the whole table. I wonder if the "show all provisions" buttons may be what's messing this up

Answer (score 0):

So `html_text` expects a node as it's input and `html_table` outputs a list of tibbles so `html_text` fails to parse this.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to parse? I just tried removing html_table and got a new error: Error in df1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I'm going to update my post with the new error

Comment: Okay so two things here:

1. It fails to parse as it's not the correct input type.

2. No surprise that it's out of bounds - `html_text` outputs a vector, not a list.

I would HIGHLY recommend you read the documentation for the functions you call. Prepending `?` or `??` to a function name will give you the docs on it, e.g. - `?html_text`